# What's the purpose of mysql@localhost (password unknown) created by the MariaDB docker image?

Tags: mariadb, docker

> Set MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER to a non-empty value to create the mysql@locahost database user. This user is especially useful for a variety of health checks and backup scripts.

But the [password is, of course, unknown](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L355). So I'm trying to figure out the purpose of this user. If it's intended to do backup and healthchecks, I can't get how to use it.

For example, take `mysqldump`, it doesn't work with socket connection and `mysql` user:

```
root@2b181d48bfc0:/# mysqldump -umysql --socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --all-databases
mysqldump: Got error: 1698: "Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost'" when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a user with unix socket authentication so needs to be run as the unix `mysql` user.

[MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_GRANTS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/#mariadb_mysql_localhost_user-mariadb_mysql_localhost_grants) as the global or all database privileges to give to this user to perform its backup/healthcheck functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand how It works! Strange thing Is the dump Is almost empty, despite the grants given (same as the official docker image docs).